# How to check if a taxonomy not exists in a plugin

Tags: plugins, php, taxonomy

I made 2 plugins (Plugin A and plugin B/custom post type.) which some of the the module on Plugin A need to call taxonomy from PLUGIN B.
Everything works fine when both plugin active, but when the Plugin B deactivate, I got this notice:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\MYWEB\InstantWP_4.3.1\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\NYPLUGIN\myplugin.php on line 50

Line 50 looks like this:

```
$option_value_event[] .= $cat->name;
```

Here the code:

```
 //Get all EVENT categories
 $args = array(
        'type'                     => 'post', 
        'child_of'                 => 0, 
        'parent'                   => '', 
        'orderby'                  => 'date', 
        'order'                    => 'ASC', 
        'hide_empty'               => 1, 
        'hierarchical'             => 1, 
        'exclude'                  => '', 
        'include'                  => '', 
        'number'                   => '', 
        'taxonomy'                 => 'catevent', 
        'pad_counts'               => false 
 ); 
 $categories_event = get_categories($args);
 $option_value_event = array();

 //Extract all EVENT categories
 foreach ( $categories_event as $cat ){ 
 $option_value_event[] .= $cat->name;
 }
```

Sometime my user dont want to use Plugin B. Is there any way to deactivate PLUGIN B without break PLUGIN A?

Is there a quick fix to resolve these error?

Really appreciate for any help

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will either need to do two things

- Check for an empty array **AND** a `WP_Error` object
- Check if the taxonomy exists (*which `get_categories()` and `get_terms()` already does*) before your execute your code and still check for an empty array

### FEW NOTES TO CONSIDER

- [`get_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) uses `get_terms()`, you you could use [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)
- You do not need to set arguments if you use it's default values
- `date` is not a valid value for `orderby` in `get_terms()`. Valid values are `name`, `slug`, `term_group`, `term_id`, `id`, `description` and `count`
- The `type` parameter in `get_categories()` does not relate to the post type, but to the taxonomy type. This parameter used to accept `link` as value and where used before the introduction of custom taxonomies in WordPress 3.0. Before WordPress 3.0, you could set `type` to `link` to return terms from the `link_category` taxonomy. This parameter was depreciated in WordPress 3.0 in favor of the `taxonomy` parameter

### SOLUTION

```
//Get all EVENT categories
$categories_event = get_terms( 'catevent' );

$option_value_event = array();  

// Check for empty array and WP_Error
if (    $categories_event
     && !is_wp_error( $categories_event )
) {
    //Extract all EVENT categories
    foreach ( $categories_event as $cat ){ 
        $option_value_event[] = $cat->name;
    }
}
```

### EDIT

I cannot see why the above code would not work. You can try the following as a test

```
if ( taxonomy_exists( 'catevent' ) ) {
    //Get all EVENT categories
    $categories_event = get_terms( 'catevent' );

    $option_value_event = array();  

    // Check for empty array and WP_Error
    if (    $categories_event
         && !is_wp_error( $categories_event )
    ) {
        //Extract all EVENT categories
        foreach ( $categories_event as $cat ){ 
            $option_value_event[] = $cat->name;
        }
    }
}
```

That should work, if not, then you have a serious error somewhere in one of your plugins

Comment: your note is very useful. I read again for codex and use it Thank a lot. But unfortunately, the notify still exist.

Comment: Sorry, there where two silly mistakes on my side. Have corrected it, please check my code again. It should work now

Comment: Same like before, the error still in there. The problem came from this line:      $option_value_event[] .= $cat->name;

Comment: See my edit. It should work now, if not, then you have a serious error somewhere else which is causing this one

Comment: `$option_value_event[] .= $cat->name` should be  `$option_value_event[] = $cat->name`

Comment: Great. It's work, and show me the error came from my PLUGIN B. Fix it and everything work fine. Thank @Pieter Goosen .

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple solution is to check if whatever is returned is empty. Always throw in these conditionals to ensure you have what you need before doing any kind of concatenation or evaluation. A simple PHP function such as [`is_empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) should suffice:

```
//Get all EVENT categories
$args = array(
        'type'                     => 'post', 
        'child_of'                 => 0, 
        'parent'                   => '', 
        'orderby'                  => 'date', 
        'order'                    => 'ASC', 
        'hide_empty'               => 1, 
        'hierarchical'             => 1, 
        'exclude'                  => '', 
        'include'                  => '', 
        'number'                   => '', 
        'taxonomy'                 => 'catevent', 
        'pad_counts'               => false 
); 
$categories_event       = get_categories( $args );
$option_value_event     = array();

//Extract all EVENT categories
if( ! empty( $categories_event ) ) {
    foreach( $categories_event as $cat ) { 
        $option_value_event[] .= $cat->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: apologize, just re-check and the problem still show up.

Comment: @Mailmulah On the same line? I imagine you'll have issues with `$option_value_event` later on too you'll need to ensure that's not empty also. `! empty( $option_value_event )` and probably other places.

Comment: Yes, in the same line. The problem is in   $option_value_event

Comment: Can you print out the contents of your array? `print_r( $categories_event );` - in theory if `catevent` doesn't exist it should be empty but I'm curious  what it holds. If it's large you can throw the gist of it into a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: I'm on mobile but I don't see where you added the conditional. And I don't need the code, just the contents of what get_categories() is returning. It *should* be empty.

Comment: Sorry, just update here for the condition http://pastebin.com/pSWayU3V . This code to display the event category from othe plugin (Plugin B.) Work fine when Plugin B active, but break up when Plugin B deactive. Plugin B is Custom post type.